# Is it possible to export markdown files written in ST3 into a google docs?

Tags: markdown, google-docs, sublimetext

i have some issues with markdown compatibility in Google docs.

I wrote my .md files in sublime-text(3) and syncing to Google drive, but there is no support for reading or previewing .md files in Google docs right know. 
I found this cool plugin called [revolunet](https://github.com/revolunet/sublimetext-markdown-preview) that can build .md to .html but then google-doc read it like a html source code.

Is there any option to save .md files to extension that is compatible with google-docs. Uberwriter markdown editor(best Ubuntu md-only editor imho) has that option --> export to html and that's it so you can read or edit your compiled html file in Google docs without any issues, but it has no cool mods like vintage mode or similar, and I would like to do all my work (coding and taking notes) in one editor, and then sync it to google drive with insync (ubuntu alternative for google drive sync).

Comment: Your question is very unclear. I don't think that Google Drive advertises Markdown support at all... Are you asking for a way to hack together a two-way sync between Drive Documents and plain-text Markdown?

Comment: @Chris - you're right, it seems that best and only solution so far is stackedit as google-drive plugin.